# How does re-index in Pandas with Series work?

Tags: pandas, series

I'm studying Pandas and Series and for educational purposes I created this example:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 8, 2], index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
s1 = s1.reindex(['a', 'b', 'e'])
print(s1)
```

My output:

```
a    1.0
b    NaN
e    NaN
dtype: float64
```

First, I don't understand why 'b' and 'e' are NaN, as there are these indices in the source index list. Also, I don't understand why the output series is float, not integer.

Comment: Looks like `s1` is some other variable defined before this, you should instead try `s1 = s.reindex(['a', 'b', 'e'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
s1 = s.reindex(['a', 'b', 'e'])
a    1
b    3
e    2
dtype: int64
```

or simple `loc`

```
s.loc[['a', 'b', 'e']]
a    1
b    3
e    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How is this not a typo?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `s1` is a variable that is defined somewhere else in the program. You can do the following instead.

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 8, 2], index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
s1 = s.reindex(['a', 'b', 'e'])
print(s1)
```

The output is:

```py
a    1
b    3
e    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: [please refrain from answering typos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) Thanks